# Accessing SQL metadata in LightSwitch

Tags: sql, metadata, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to access extended properties in my SQL database in LightSwitch. Ideally I would be able to populate a choicelist based on these extended properties - namely picklist values.

Is there any way in which I can do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Jimmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expose the extended properties from SQL Server with a view or stored proc and then access it like regular application data.

Try this bundle of links which accompany my presentation on metadata: https://bitly.com/bundles/caderoux/3

Answer (score 0):

WCF RIA Service is always your answer. You can do anything.